# Using a function or calculation to refer to a SAS field name?

Tags: sas

I need to populate a series of columns titled M0, M1, M2, etc.  Below is the long-hand logic I've worked out, but now I'd like to streamline the code.  See how I first count the months between two date fields to learn what column to populate.

```
if intck('month', start_dt, today_dt) = 0 then M0 = "Blue";
if intck('month', start_dt, today_dt) = 1 then M1 = "Blue";
if intck('month', start_dt, today_dt) = 2 then M2 = "Blue";
```

Conceptually I'd rather do something like this on a singular line of code instead:

```
"M"||intck('month', start_dt, today_dt) = "Blue";
```

So I want to "calculate" the proper column name, I guess.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what an ARRAY is for.

```
array month [0:3] m0-m3;
month[intck('month', start_dt, today_dt)]= "Blue";
```

In reality you will want to make sure the index is a valid value before using it.

```
array month[0:3] m0-m3;
index= intck('month', start_dt, today_dt) ;
if index in (0:3) then month[index] = "Blue";
else put 'Month out of range ' index= start_dt= ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was able to fashion this into a solution!  However, I think i am missing a detail as I had to fiddle a bit to stop firing out of range errors.  Here's how I did that.  Is there a more straightforward way?  Note I've ensured every record of my set dataset has between zero and 24 months between complete_mo and filemonth_dt.

Comment: array perfmo [1:25] M0-M24;

Comment: perfmo[sum(intck('month', complete_mo, filemonth_dt), 1)] = dq_to_use;

Comment: You can see I took steps to turn the range from 0-24 to 1-25.  While this works fine, it's not ideal because the next user will have to figure out that I'm making this adjustment.  Again, thanks so much!

Comment: INTCK() will return the number of interval boundaries crossed, so dates in the same month will return zero.  You can define the ARRAY to use any range of integers you want as the index.  See the `[0:3]` in my example. Since the variables are also named with number suffixes that start with zero this will make it much less confusing for the programmer.  So index 0 will point to the first variable, m0. And index 3 will point to the fourth variable, m3.

Comment: oh, it just clicked.  I do have some records without a filemonth_dt, so when intck() returns null, I'm out of range.  And my workaround is putting it back in range by adding the 1.  I think I get it now.   I will execute conditionally as you suggest.  Can't wait to find more applications for this!   Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77305441/10871073), you could put the logic for the number of month intervals between `start_dt` and `today_dt` into a `do` loop and use the variable, `i`, to represent the months.

So you could, for example, create `i=12` months in the `do` loop, calculate the interval and create the 12 month variables (`M0`-`M11`), assigning each a value equal to your original equation:

```
M[i] = intck('month', start_dt, today_dt)
```

Applying a format assigns the number of intervals to a color, e.g. 0 to 2 intervals (or months 1 to 3) are assigned `Blue`:

```
proc format;
        value color
            0-2 = 'Blue'
            3-5 = 'Red'
            6-8 = 'Green'
            9-11 = 'Yellow';
run;


data want_color_months;
    today_dt = today();

    array M[*] M0-M11;
    do i = 1 to dim(M);
        start_dt = today() - 30*(i-1);
        M[i] = intck('month', start_dt, today_dt);
        put "NOTE: the color for month " i "  is: " M[i];
    end;
    format M: color. today_dt start_dt date9.;  
    drop i start_dt;
run;

Log:
NOTE: the color for month 1   is: Blue
NOTE: the color for month 2   is: Blue
NOTE: the color for month 3   is: Blue
NOTE: the color for month 4   is: Red
NOTE: the color for month 5   is: Red
NOTE: the color for month 6   is: Red
NOTE: the color for month 7   is: Green
NOTE: the color for month 8   is: Green
NOTE: the color for month 9   is: Green
NOTE: the color for month 10   is: Yellow
NOTE: the color for month 11   is: Yellow
NOTE: the color for month 12   is: Yellow
```